# android unittest got instrument.IllegalClassFormatException, and why it complains "(have Java 1)."?

Tags: robolectric, android-unit-testing

Having an android library project, it has been built and unit tested fine with android studio 4.1.2. Now change to use android studio (fox) 2020.3.1 path 3.

It starts to get error `Cannot run gradle test tasks because of java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/internal/reflect/GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor1`.

after added `task.jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']`:

```
plugins.withId("jacoco") {
        tasks.withType(Test) { task ->
            task.jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
            task.jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*'] //<=== added this line
        }
    }
```

the error disappeared, but now got:

```
java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: Error while instrumenting com/mobile/notification/NotificationModule.
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:94)
        at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:246)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:563)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
.........

        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while instrumenting com/mobile/notification/NotificationModule.
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrumentError(Instrumenter.java:160)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:110)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:92)
        ... 64 more
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot process instrumented class com/mobile/notification/NotificationModule. Please supply original non-instrumented classes.
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.core.internal.instr.InstrSupport.assertNotInstrumented(InstrSupport.java:238)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.core.internal.instr.ClassInstrumenter.visitField(ClassInstrumenter.java:56)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.asm.ClassVisitor.visitField(ClassVisitor.java:339)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.asm.ClassReader.readField(ClassReader.java:1111)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:713)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:401)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:90)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:108)
        ... 65 more

[Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 16 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 16 unless explicitly requested.
[Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 17 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 17 unless explicitly requested.
[Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 18 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 18 unless explicitly requested.
[Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 19 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 19 unless explicitly requested.
[Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 21 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 21 unless explicitly requested.
[Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 22 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 22 unless explicitly requested.
[Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 23 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 23 unless explicitly requested.
[Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 24 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 24 unless explicitly requested.
[Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 25 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 25 unless explicitly requested.
[Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 26 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 26 unless explicitly requested.
[Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 27 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 27 unless explicitly requested.
[Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 28 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 28 unless explicitly requested.
[Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 29 requires Java 9 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 29 unless explicitly requested.

Failed to create a Robolectric sandbox: Android SDK 28 requires Java 8 (have Java 1)
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to create a Robolectric sandbox: Android SDK 28 requires Java 8 (have Java 1)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getSandbox(RobolectricTestRunner.java:265)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getSandbox(RobolectricTestRunner.java:63)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:215)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$1.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:96)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:119)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

the project has

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

and

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.3-bin.zip


android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion 30.0.0

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName version

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        
    }
```

and other related:

```
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"

        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.7"

...
testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
testApi "org.robolectric:robolectric:4,3,1"
```

what does the error `IllegalStateException: Cannot process instrumented class ... Please supply original non-instrumented classes.` mean?  and why it complains about it has `have Java 1` where there is `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` specified?

in the project's resourcec folder it also has `robolectric.properties` which has `sdk=28` to ask it using api version 28.

question is what might be missing, since it has been working fine in android studio 4.1.2.

Comment: The error suggests that it can't find a suitable version of Java to work with. So the first step is to look up how to make sure to run through your tool's installation instructions again, and triple check you've exactly what they tell you to do, in the exact order they say to do things in.